# "LightGBMError: Do not support special JSON characters in feature name"

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lightgbm

My 'X' data is a pandas data frame of time-series. I extracted features of X data using Tsfresh and try to apply LightGBM algorithm to classify the data into 0(Bad) and 1(Good). But it shows an error. Columns of my X data are`

Index(['0__ratio_beyond_r_sigma__r_1',
'0__change_quantiles__f_agg_"mean"**isabs_True__qh_0.8__ql_0.0',
'0__cwt_coefficients__coeff_1__w_20__widths*(2, 5, 10, 20)',
'0__cwt_coefficients__coeff_1__w_10__widths*(2, 5, 10, 20)',
'0__change_quantiles__f_agg_"var"_*isabs_False__qh_0.8__ql_0.0',
'0__change_quantiles__f_agg*"mean"_*isabs_True__qh_0.4__ql_0.0',
'0__change_quantiles__f_agg*"mean"_*isabs_True__qh_0.8__ql_0.6',
'0__change_quantiles__f_agg*"mean"_*isabs_False__qh_0.4__ql_0.0',
'0__fft_coefficient__attr*"real"_*coeff_3',
'0__change_quantiles__f_agg*"mean"_*isabs_True__qh_1.0__ql_0.0',
...
'0__quantile__q_0.4', '0__fft_coefficient__attr*"imag"**coeff_39',
'0__large_standard_deviation__r_0.2',
'0__cwt_coefficients__coeff_13__w_10__widths*(2, 5, 10, 20)',
'0__fourier_entropy__bins_10',
'0__fft_coefficient__attr*"angle"_*coeff_9',
'0__fft_coefficient__attr*"imag"_*coeff_17',
'0__fft_coefficient__attr*"angle"_*coeff_92', '0__maximum',
'0__fft_coefficient__attr*"imag"__coeff_32'],
dtype='object', length=225)

My code is
`

```
import lightgbm as lgb
d_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)



lgbm_params = {'learning_rate':0.05, 'boosting_type':'dart',   
              'objective':'binary',
              'metric':['auc', 'binary_logloss'],
              'num_leaves':100,
              'max_depth':10}


clf = lgb.train(lgbm_params, d_train, 50) 




y_pred_lgbm=clf.predict(X_test)


for i in range(0, X_test.shape[0]):
    if y_pred_lgbm[i]>=.5:       
       y_pred_lgbm[i]=1
    else:  
       y_pred_lgbm[i]=0
       


cm_lgbm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_lgbm)
sns.heatmap(cm_lgbm, annot=True)
```

`

I tried below code to change my columns but it does not work.
`

```
import re
X = X.rename(columns = lambda u:re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9_]+', '', u))
```

After applying that rename function the columns looks as below
`

```
Index(['0__ratio_beyond_r_sigma__r_1',
       '0__change_quantiles__f_agg_mean__isabs_True__qh_08__ql_00',
       '0__cwt_coefficients__coeff_1__w_20__widths_251020',
       '0__cwt_coefficients__coeff_1__w_10__widths_251020',
       '0__change_quantiles__f_agg_var__isabs_False__qh_08__ql_00',
       '0__change_quantiles__f_agg_mean__isabs_True__qh_04__ql_00',
       '0__change_quantiles__f_agg_mean__isabs_True__qh_08__ql_06',
       '0__change_quantiles__f_agg_mean__isabs_False__qh_04__ql_00',
       '0__fft_coefficient__attr_real__coeff_3',
       '0__change_quantiles__f_agg_mean__isabs_True__qh_10__ql_00',
       ...
       '0__quantile__q_04', '0__fft_coefficient__attr_imag__coeff_39',
       '0__large_standard_deviation__r_02',
       '0__cwt_coefficients__coeff_13__w_10__widths_251020',
       '0__fourier_entropy__bins_10',
       '0__fft_coefficient__attr_angle__coeff_9',
       '0__fft_coefficient__attr_imag__coeff_17',
       '0__fft_coefficient__attr_angle__coeff_92', '0__maximum',
       '0__fft_coefficient__attr_imag__coeff_32'],
      dtype='object', length=225)
```

`
What should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

u cant put like '_' these kind of symbol in column names or the lgb will report this kind of error